# Copying one data frame into another

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I am trying to add the data from one data frame into a much larger data frame. Basically, in my case "df" is a data frame where the row lengths are 376, but I want to put these 376 items into "data" which will have row lengths of 10000. The reason I am doing this is because while my data in "df" is capped at 376 items per row, each row is not complete and I am going to concatenate rows together once I get them into the larger "data" data frame. The issue with my code shown below is that when I try transferring a row of "df" into a row of "data", I get numbers instead of some letter name that should be shown in place (I'm assuming the numbers are the location of the item in memory). How do I fix my code so that I get the actual item names transferred over to "data"?

```
df<-read.table("msigdb.v5.2.symbols.txt", fill = TRUE)
data<-data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol = 10000, nrow = 19337))
for (w in 1:20){
data[w,]<-df[w,]
}
```

data[1,1] should be "AAANWWTGC_UNKNOWN", instead I am just getting "5"

Comment: Hi, welcome to *Stack Overflow*, in order that we can help you best, please provide example data. Consider [*How to make a great reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038), thanks.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas even with using put(head(df,20)) the output is too large to post here. I am using the downloadable link from the msigdb website and analyzing the genes in that file if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

That is due to that you are replacing a row in a `data.frame` that contain factors to a data.frame that contains logical values, and the default will be to convert the `df` values to integers.

Look at the two examples below:

**1) matrix to data.frame**

```
data<-data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol = 3, nrow = 3))
df<-(matrix(data=rep(c("pos1","pos2",3),3),nrow=3,byrow=FALSE))

str(df)
 chr [1:3, 1:3] "pos1" "pos2" "3" "pos1" "pos2" "3" "pos1" "pos2" "3"

str(data)
 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1: logi  NA NA NA
 $ X2: logi  NA NA NA
 $ X3: logi  NA NA NA

data[1,]<-df[1,]

str(data)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1: chr  "pos1" NA NA
 $ X2: chr  "pos1" NA NA
 $ X3: chr  "pos1" NA NA
```

**2) data.frame to data.frame**

```
data<-data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol = 3, nrow = 3))
df<-data.frame(matrix(data=rep(c("pos1","pos2",3),3),nrow=3,byrow=FALSE))

str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1: Factor w/ 3 levels "3","pos1","pos2": 2 3 1
 $ X2: Factor w/ 3 levels "3","pos1","pos2": 2 3 1
 $ X3: Factor w/ 3 levels "3","pos1","pos2": 2 3 1

str(data)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1: logi  NA NA NA
 $ X2: logi  NA NA NA
 $ X3: logi  NA NA NA

data[1,]<-df[1,]

str(data)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1: int  2 NA NA
 $ X2: int  2 NA NA
 $ X3: int  2 NA NA
```

Comment: thank you! But I am still getting an error when I try importing df in the format of a matrix and adding it to data:

Comment: <df<-matrix(read.table("msigdb.v5.2.symbols.txt", fill = TRUE))> when I use that code and do data[1,]<-df[1,] I get the error: 
<Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, , value = list(c(5L, 6L, 18543L,  :
  replacement element 1 has 19336 rows to replace 1 rows>

Why is that? @nadizan

Comment: Because that you are somehow replacing a row with a list. Make sure that you do not have any lists!